# Excel 2010 : Auto Populate cells

Tags: microsoft-excel-2016

I have been using Excel for quite a while, but have never dove into its capabilities until now.  I have cells (`C4` and `H4`) that I would like to auto populate with "0004" but only if data is entered into cell `A4`. If there is no data in cell `A4` then I would like it to remain blank.  I have tried:

```
=IF(A2=" "," ","0004),
```

but it only displays the formula and does not function properly. I have tried to use the same formula in data validation, but again, it does not work.

Comment: If it only displays the formula but does not actually calculate, make sure the cells are not formatted as text only and make sure auto calculation are turned on

Comment: I did have the cell formatted as text.  i changed that to General, but when I put the formula mentioned above in, it just enters the "0004".  It is not contingent on whether or not A2 has any data in it or not.

Comment: your formula should be =IF(A2="","","0004") without spaces in the quotes.

Comment: That is what my problem was.  Thank you so much for your help!  Have a great day!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it only displays the formula but does not actually calculate, make sure the cells are not formatted as text only and make sure auto calculation are turned on – Eric F May 26 at 14:20

I did have the cell formatted as text. i changed that to General, but when I put the formula mentioned above in, it just enters the "0004". It is not contingent on whether or not A2 has any data in it or not. – R.Conklin May 26 at 14:27

your formula should be =IF(A2="","","0004") without spaces in the quotes. – Eric F May 26 at 14:28

That is what my problem was. Thank you so much for your help! Have a great day! – R.Conklin May 26 at 14:31